# BeautifulSoup get a certain value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using a really simple thing to get the information I need:

```
a = soup.find_all(class_ = "pull-right hidden-phone")
print(a)
print(a[0])
```

And the output is:

```
[<span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="190000000" data-time="1535345254000">1.9 BTC</span></span>, <span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="4890548" data-time="1535345254000">0.04890548 BTC</span></span>]
<span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="190000000" data-time="1535345254000">1.9 BTC</span></span>
```

I want to get 1.9 BTC or 190000000 but don't know how to.
I've tried `print(a[0]["data-time"])` and that doesn't work, it says

> return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 'data-time'

However, this `print(a[0]["class"])` works and gives the `['pull-right', 'hidden-phone']` as a result.

So how can I get a 1.9 BTC or 190000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this way, May this help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """
<span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="190000000" data-time="1535345254000">1.9 BTC</span></span>, 
<span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="4890548" data-time="1535345254000">0.04890548 BTC</span></span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'pull-right hidden-phone'}):
    span_tag = tag.span
    print('Attribute Value:', span_tag.get('data-c'), 'Date-time:', span_tag.get('data-time'), 'Tag Text:', span_tag.get_text())


# Output as: 
# Attribute Value: 190000000 Date-time: 1535345254000 Tag Text: 1.9 BTC
# Attribute Value: 4890548 Date-time: 1535345254000 Tag Text: 0.04890548 BTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(a.find("span").span["data-time"])` or `print(a.span.span["data-time"])`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<span class="pull-right hidden-phone"><span data-c="190000000" data-time="1535345254000">1.9 BTC</span></span>"""
a = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

print(a.find("span").span["data-time"])
print(a.span.span["data-c"])
print(a.span.span.text)
```

**Output:**

```
1535345254000
190000000
1.9 BTC
```